# Change icon on click and then revert to original on next click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of tabs that when you click on one, the background color changes to red. If you have not clicked on a tab, the background is white. There is an icon in each tab, colored white (if you clicked on the tab) or red (if you are not clicking on the tab). I am having difficulties getting the icon to change to the right color when the tabs are clicked (or not clicked). The icons are images, by the way.

This is what I have so far. I am able to get the background colors to change but not sure how I should go about switching the image. The active-tab class is controlling the background color.

```js
if($('.tab-container').length > 0){

  $('.tab a').on('click', function(e){
    $('.tab').removeClass('active-tab');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active-tab');
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','https://img-21.ccm2.net/1-NtiXuJNqGFChdD_IIpOnM9aOA=/200x/31027358c0f24fd3bd484a485b5a652c/ccm-faq/1538-9tLde1xY3nSyajQH-s-.png');
  });


}
```

```css
img{
  width: 48px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tab-container'>
         <div class='tab'>
           <a href='#this-is-the-first-tab' id='this-is-the-fist-tab'>
            <img src='https://n6-img-fp.akamaized.net/icones-gratis/inicio-icone-silhouette_318-85097.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg' class='tab-icon'> 
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if ($('.tab-container').length > 0) {
  $('.tab img').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.tab-icon').toggleClass('active-tab')
  });
}
```

```css
 .active-tab{
    content:url("https://n6-img-fp.akamaized.net/icones-gratis/inicio-icone-silhouette_318-85097.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tab-container'>
  <div class='tab'>
    <a href='#this-is-the-first-tab' id='this-is-the-fist-tab'>
      <img height="50" width="50" id="x" src='https://img-21.ccm2.net/1-NtiXuJNqGFChdD_IIpOnM9aOA=/200x/31027358c0f24fd3bd484a485b5a652c/ccm-faq/1538-9tLde1xY3nSyajQH-s-.png' class='tab-icon'>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can add the image src to active-tab class and it should switch just like the background.

```
.active-tab{
content:url("//tab-icon-default.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the parent has the class `active-tab`, if yes, change the image and then remove the class. 
This answer is just a help to the logic, maybe you'll need to change accordlying to your need, but this is a way to follow.
Take a look at the snippet.

```js
if($('.tab-container').length > 0){
  $('.tab a').on('click', function(e){
    
    var myPath = '';
    if ($('.tab').hasClass('active-tab')){
      myPath='https://n6-img-fp.akamaized.net/icones-gratis/inicio-icone-silhouette_318-85097.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg';
      $('.tab').removeClass('active-tab');

    }else{
      myPath = 'https://img-21.ccm2.net/1-NtiXuJNqGFChdD_IIpOnM9aOA=/200x/31027358c0f24fd3bd484a485b5a652c/ccm-faq/1538-9tLde1xY3nSyajQH-s-.png';
      $('.tab').addClass('active-tab');
    }
    
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', myPath);
  });
}
```

```css
img{
  width: 48px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tab-container'>
         <div class='tab'>
           <a href='#this-is-the-first-tab' id='this-is-the-fist-tab'>
            <img src='https://n6-img-fp.akamaized.net/icones-gratis/inicio-icone-silhouette_318-85097.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg' class='tab-icon'> 
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I borrowed your image urls hope that is ok.

Comment: ok, it's not mine, it's from google... :D Also, i suggested an edit to OP using this same images

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest instead, to use a css on the `img` tag, that when it is clicked, the color changes without you changing the actual image source (it will have some browser compatibility issues though).

Example that works on hover:

```css
body {
 background: #444;
}

.square {
 width: 10rem;
 height: 10rem;
 background: #fff;
 display: block;
}

.square:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.35) sepia(1)
 hue-rotate(310deg) saturate(7);
 }
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: OP wants to be on click, and also he wants to change image, if you want to suggest something, do this in the comments

Comment: I used the hover as an example. He clearly already understands how to add a class to modify styles. He also stated in the question "I am having difficulties getting the icon to change to the right color when the tabs are clicked", not that he wanted the image to change. I'm offering a solution to his problem; it may not be the solution he expected because I'm not changing the img src, but it is still a valid solution.